# Stacking multi-dimensional bands in rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, numpy

I'm trying to stack numpy arrays to write a TIFF file:

```
stacked_bands = []
    for i in range(1, 37):
        stacked_bands.append(np.stack(([get_window(t, x, y, i) for t in tif_files])))
```

`stacked_bands` is a list containing 36 arrays of shape (6, 121, 121). This does work and the resulting list and its contents are what I want them to be.

I'm then trying to write them to file:

```
 with rasterio.open(out_tif, 'w', **out_meta) as dst:      
        for num, band in enumerate(stacked_bands, start=1):
            dst.write(band, num)
```

I also tried using `dst.write_band`, which results in python telling me, the positional argument must be an array-like object (which, to my understanding, it is).
The example above yields:

```
ValueError: Source shape (1, 6, 121, 121) is inconsistent with given indexes 1
```

I don't understand what this message is referring to. Where is the '1' coming from and where were the indexes specified as per the `ValueError`?
I read something about specifying the order bands, rows and cols, is it possible that `rasterio` expects the input to be 'nested'?

As a side note, at the end I don't care for the rasterio datasets/TIFF files, I just need the arrays of shape(36, 6, 121, 121) but each with a label (for machine learning) and I don't know any other way to retain this information through different rounds of manipulation.

Comment: You can't write arrays with > 3 dims (such as shape == (36, 6, 121, 121) ) to a tif.  You can write a 3 dim array - shape == (z, y, x) or (bands, rows, cols) e.g. (6, 121, 121) with `dst.write(3Darray)` or a single 2 dim band - shape == (rows, cols) with `dst.write(2Darray, band_index)`.  You need to use a multidimensional format and library if you want to handle multidimensional arrays, have a look at `xarray`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a perfect answer. I'll look into `xarray`.

Comment: You might also look into [structured arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) if you want to stick with plain numpy and ND arrays.

Comment: Thanks again. I had a look at both. But now I wonder if it would be bad practice to just use a tuple? Like `x = ('label', np.array(...))`, since `dicts` wouldn't work (arrays not hashable). Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Dicts work fine. `labels = {'label': array}` is what you want.  Obviously you can't use the array as the key... `labels = {array: 'label'}` is _not_ what you want `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: Yes, but the keys have to be unique, right? And I have many arrays that could be labelled as one of three possible classes. There are workarounds but in the end i just used tuples and pickled them. I also tried the structured arrays approach but I'm not sure if there are benefits with `numpy.save()`. It's supposed to be more efficient with numeric data but sinceI also have the labels.. In the end, it doesn't matter, it took the server forever, but it has to be done only once